Make local git as Single Branch after cloning
I started a git repo a few years ago, and now the repo has become huge. The .git folder is huge with more 50GB after applying How to shrink the .git folder.
The number of remote branches is huge as well, is there a way to make my local git repo as "Single Branch" without re-clone it?

Why do you commit binary files in your Git repository? :)

I don't :) It is a MASSIVE code base

I suggest to you to clone it again, but providing a specific branch as source by the following command:
git clone -b <branch-name> --single-branch <repository-url>
Instead, if you need to work with a bunch of specific branches, you should try with the following steps:
# Initialize a new empty local repository

mkdir <repository-name>
cd <repository-name>
git init

# Add the remote repo url

git remote add -f origin <repository-url>

# Enable sparse-checkout (for this repo only)

git config core.sparseCheckout true

# Declare which branches you want to pull each time you issue a pull command

echo "my_branch1/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "my_branch2/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

# Pull your remote branches

git pull origin master # Or "main"

